WinForm hidden behind task bar after scaling my monitor
I have a win form that scales itself correctly (based on what the monitor has) but the form than becomes too big so a part of the form gets hidden behind the task bar and the top is cut off (see photo).
Info:
Win form is being called by an outlook add-in.
Target framework: .net framework 4.8
Monitor Resolution: 1920x1080
Monitor Scaling: 150%
How it is =>
Win form with 150% scaling
How it should be/full form is seen here => Win form with 100% scaling
I've tried scaling it different (none, font, dpi), the autoScroll doesnt work because the form thinks it is small enough. Max and min sizes are set. AutoSize doesnt do anything, that could help.
The only think that has helped till now is, making the win form smaller so that I force it, to always have a scroll bar, but I dont like this solution.
And I have not found anything else or anyone describing the same problem.
Update
WPF ClickOnce DPI
and
DPI Awareness
didn't really help. The second link I didn't really understand but they referenced the first which I did try even though it was for WPF and not win form.
In a different answer it said I should add
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
    <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>

but it didn't make a difference.
Also I don't have a Program.cs because I am doing a VISTO Outlook Add-In, so I upt the OnStartup code in the Outlook -> AddIn.cs. It compiles  but it doesn't scale.

Make the form smaller so it fits.

I have a win form that scales itself correctly: how does it scale? Did you write some logic to manage this behavior? In you test Project, did you actually enable some form of DpiAwareness? If that's the case, which one and how? -- If you test Project does not consider any form of DpiAwareness (i.e., it's Dpi-Unaware, the default in .NET Framework Projects), when it becomes part of a Process that instead has an active DpiAwareness mode enabled, it becomes DpiAware itself (System-Aware, i.e., aware of the Dpi state of the primary monitor when the User first logged in)

Test your Form in a PerMonitorV2 DpiAware Project, design it at 100% scale (it appears you're not actually doing that, based on the images you posted). Now you get real measures and also notifications when the Dpi changes, so you can act on it. Read the notes here: DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other

Hey, sorry for the long wait. So I didnt write any logic for scalling. the window sizes up and doesn't take the "new height" into consideration. Than the window is to big to be shown on the scaled monitor.
I didn't know about DpiAwareness and have now added app.manifest howerer I am having trouble with understanding the DpiAwarenessContext (Windows 10, version 1809). The veriables aren't recodnized and i'm not quite sure where I should put it.

With the manifasat file and properties set to [AutoScaleMode = None; AutoScroll = True; AutoSize = False; AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink] it sometimes works. The window becomes smaller and I'm able to use it normaly but that is not always the case and I haven't figured out when it does or doesn't work.
